# How to upload files to a MODERN openshift?

Tags: upload, openshift

I have the modern openshift that forces you to login with github as a result i cant sign in with the rhc thing and get access to the ftp stuff to upload my files like you are meant to. What is the way of uploading files on the new openshift? I have nodejs content i would like to upload to it.

Comment: It doesn't work like old school web hosting where you ftp stuff up to the server. Suggest you read the free eBook about it at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html It uses Java examples, but what you need to understand from that first is how source-to-image (S2I) builders work and how you interact with the platform, so work through the examples in the book anyway. Then you can tackle using the S2I builder for node.js. https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/latest/using_images/s2i_images/nodejs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming you had choose **nodejs-mongo-persistent** Quick-Start. In order to do that, create a exact replica of [Node-js Quick-Start repository](https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex) in your own git account. (You can use [Import feature](https://github.com/new/import) of Git-hub)
While you creating the project you have to put your own git repository url in **Git Repository URL** space. Then hit Create

Next, you have to clone your newly created repository to local machine (`git clone repo_url.git`) 
 Just modify the Quick-Start Node-js project and commit then push to git.
 Then login to your OpenShift-v3 using Command Line Tools. (Assuming you already configured it properly).

Run the following commands 
`oc start-build nodejs-mongo-persistent` (It will take some time to complete; around 10 mins) 
Then run `oc deploy nodejs-mongo-persistent --latest`

That's it

Comment: Can u please explain how to commit and push to git? i dont really use or know github i only got one mostly to use this, so im not to familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry it dosent matter the website located inside openshift told me how to do it. It didn't work at first probably wasn't ready at that time.

Comment: This may help you to push files to github [LINK](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line/)

Comment: Ok thanks for the good answer but i think openshift is not right for me because then people on github can steal my code and i dont want them to so i will go with a alternative now that dosent require it!

Comment: Yes but for some reason my app had connection problems with it but im trying lots of other methods and stuff wish me luck!